# How do I get Pylance's type checking to work with this Pydantic example?

Tags: python, typechecking, pydantic, pylance

I'm discovering Pydantic and I see this in an example (https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#recursive-models):

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Foo(BaseModel):
    count: int
    size: float = None
```

I'm using VS Code and Pylance, and until now, I had been ignoring Pylance's type checking functionality because I have multiple instances where I need to be able to set None as the default to a field that doesn't have None in its type annotation.

I see this in Pydantic, and Pydantic works fine with Pylance, but as is with all the other times I've tried to set a default of None to a field not annotated with None, Pylance flags it with a `Expression of type "None" cannot be assigned to declared type` problem.

I figure that if it's meant to work in Pydantic, and it doesn't for me, there has to be something I'm missing.

I've set up VS Code as per https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/visual_studio_code/ and it still seems to not work.

Comment: If you think about, it makes perfect sense.

On one hand, you are telling `Pylance` - "Hey, I'm going to store a `float` value in this variable", and then a second later you go "But in the meantime, let's store a None there".

Pylance clearly doesn't like that, and that's good.

Comment: @harmag I'm aware that it makes sense. I'm not asking whether or not it's "good", I'm asking whether or not I can do it.

Comment: The linked example has since been updated. `size: Optional[float] = None` is correct for python<=3.9, and `size: float | None = None` for  python>=3.10 ~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fields that accept `None` as value can be declared using `typing.Optional`:

```python
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional

class Foo(BaseModel):
    count: int
    size: Optional[float] = None
```

See [Field Types](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/) in the pydantic documentation for more information about the supported field types:

> `typing.Optional`
>
> `Optional[x]` is simply short hand for `Union[x, None]`; see [Unions](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#unions) below for more detail on parsing and validation and [Required Fields](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#required-fields) for details about required fields that can receive `None` as a value.

Comment: I'm not looking for `typing.Optional` "...because I have multiple instances where I need to be able to set None as the default to a field that doesn't have None in its type annotation."

Comment: In the Pydantic example that I've linked, it does not use `Optional`.

Comment: That is most likely an error of the documentation. I would bet that `Optional` is correct as the Pylance correctly informs the user that `None` is not a valid float.

Comment: @lapraswastaken, the example you linked now uses `Optional`. It was an error in the documentation.